# SQL Server 2012: How can a column-store index provide multiple columns at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, columnstore

Let's say we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
 ID INT,
 String1 nvarchar(400),
 String2 nvarchar(400)
)
```

And a query:

```
select String1, String2, count(*)
from T
group by String1, String2
```

If T was indexed by a [column-store index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), this grouping query would generally be driven by a non-clustered column-store index scan.

**If a column-store index stores rows in a column-by-column format, and each column is sorted individually, how can it then provide multiple columns per row at once?** This seems to be impossible because the individual columns are sorted in different sort orders. I can't think of any way to merge the individual columns back into a full row containing both columns (String1, String2 in this example).

How does this work internally?

Comment: The internals of column store indexes aren't well documented at the moment (and not sure they will ever be as the documentation repeatedly refers to proprietary methods). You might find [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10529/3690) (and the links in the comments) useful though. The power point presentation talks about segment keys and join indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column is stored separately, so the system has to do multiple accesses to the column indexes (one per column selected) and then internally join the results together to return the final query result.  This is still quite efficient as the column store indexes dramatically reduce the I/O required, although a large number of columns queried might be slow.